# Is it natural to say "I want to swim to the edge of the pool"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

You are swimming in the middle of the pool and suddenly you feel tired. And you want to move to the edge of the pool to take a rest.

It seems that native speakers suggest "**I want to get out of the pool**".

But I don't want to get out of the pool. I want to move to the edge of the pool (because it's safer)  to take a rest.

Is it ok to say "**I want to swim ashore**" or "**I want to swim to the edge of the pool**" in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

“Ashore” would normally imply a natural edge like a beach or the side of a lake, not the edge of a pool. “I want to swim to the edge of the pool” is fine, but “I want to swim to the edge” or “I want to swim to the side” would probably be more natural.

Comment: Plus even if you were talking about a lake, "swimming ashore" would strongly suggest getting out of the water, which the OP said he didn't want to do.